# Randomizing Background Images in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm building a simple app that displays random quotations. I'd like to add and randomize a series of background images, but I'm stuck. Here's what I have so far. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblQuote: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgBackground: UIImageView!

    var quoteArray = ["Hustle is the dark horse of creativity,\n the close cousin of Grit and Tenacity.\n Without the hustle, drive, and complete devotion to making things happen, you are average.\n\n- Rebecca Rebouché ",
        "What you want to do is not study in some prestigious field,\nbut study something that a prestigious field will grow out of.\n That’s the really big win.\n\n - Paul Graham",
        "There’s nothing like being tossed into necessity to help you figure out who you are and what matters most in life –\n necessity may be the mother of invention, but it’s even more so the fairy godmother of self-invention.\n\n - Maria Popova",
        "Pursuing that feeling of not really knowing what to do,and choosing what doesn’t quite seem like the logical next step, but feels right at a gut level, is how I’ve pieced together where I am today. It’s about that combination of anxiety about going into territory where I’m totally unfamiliar, and not knowing a big chunk of it.\n\n - Liz Danzico",
        "On the fringes...is where disruptive innovation begins.\n\n - Neri Oxman",
        "I wanted to be a certain kind of woman.\n I became that kind of woman.\n\n - Diane von Furstenburg"]

    var imageArray  = [
        UIImage(named: "boldlivingbackground.png"),
        UIImage(named: "background1.png"),
        UIImage(named: "background2.png"),
        UIImage(named: "background3.png"),
        UIImage(named: "background4.png"),
        UIImage(named: "background5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "background6.png"),
    ]

    var numberQuote = 0
    var numberImage = 0
    var numberButton = 0
    var numberCheck = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func btnExploreOtherQuotes(sender: UIButton) {
        selectQuote()
    }

    func selectQuote() {      
        numberQuote = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))      
        while numberCheck == numberQuote {
            numberQuote = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray.count)))
        }
        printQuote()
        numberCheck = numberQuote
    }

    func printQuote() {
        lblQuote.text = "\(quoteArray[numberQuote])"
    }

    func selectImage() {     
        numberImage = Int(arc4random_uniform(60))      
        while numberCheck == numberImage {
            numberImage = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageArray.count)))
        }
        numberCheck = numberImage
    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you're "stuck"? What specifically are you stuck on? What is actually happening in comparison to the expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry. I thought my post made it clear that I'm not sure how to randomize background images, despite having successfully randomized the quotes. Specifically, I don't understand how to display a random image from an array along with a random quote from a separate array.

Comment: When are you calling `selectImage()`? Shouldn't it be called in `btnExploreOtherQuotes(...)`? Where do you actually set this new image you randomly selected?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a working project [from here](https://bitbucket.org/abizern/so-32954762/get/c7e464fdf1a6.zip)

You can do all you want with this:

Note, Rather than create an array of images, which uses more memory than you really want to, create an array of names which are used to generate the images.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var quoteLabel: UILabel!

    let quotes = [
        "Hustle is the dark horse of creativity,\n the close cousin of Grit and Tenacity.\n Without the hustle, drive, and complete devotion to making things happen, you are average.\n\n- Rebecca Rebouché ",
        "What you want to do is not study in some prestigious field,\nbut study something that a prestigious field will grow out of.\n That’s the really big win.\n\n - Paul Graham",
        "There’s nothing like being tossed into necessity to help you figure out who you are and what matters most in life –\n necessity may be the mother of invention, but it’s even more so the fairy godmother of self-invention.\n\n - Maria Popova",
        "Pursuing that feeling of not really knowing what to do,and choosing what doesn’t quite seem like the logical next step, but feels right at a gut level, is how I’ve pieced together where I am today. It’s about that combination of anxiety about going into territory where I’m totally unfamiliar, and not knowing a big chunk of it.\n\n - Liz Danzico",
        "On the fringes...is where disruptive innovation begins.\n\n - Neri Oxman",
        "I wanted to be a certain kind of woman.\n I became that kind of woman.\n\n - Diane von Furstenburg"
    ]

    // These are just vector solid colours stored in the Asset Catalogue.
    let images = [
        "Image1",
        "Image2",
        "Image3",
        "Image4",
        "Image5",
        "Image6"
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
    }

    @IBAction func onNext(sender: UIButton) {
        setupView()
    }

    private func randomImage() -> UIImage {
        let idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
        guard let image = UIImage(named: images[idx]) else { fatalError() }

        return image
    }

    private func randomQuote() -> String {
        let idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count)))
        return quotes[idx]
    }

    private func setupView() {
        imageView.image = randomImage()
        quoteLabel.text = randomQuote()
    }

}
```